# Walking from Santiago to Buenos Aires

Tags: walking, buenos-aires, santiago-de-chile

I am wondering if it's possible (and safe) to walk from Santiago to Buenos Aires. Does anyone have experience with this? Any tips or advise is welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. This site calls for factual answers to questions, not advice. Also, safety is a relative and subjective notion

Comment: Santiago de Chile?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so random about this. I have not worked out the idea very concrete and you were right to tell me so. Still, I'm the kind of person that follows through random ideas and I really want to do this.. For now I just have the intention to go by foot from Santiago to Buenos Aires. So do you guys have any ideas about this?

Comment: I presume you could walk alongside the RN7 and hike above the tunnels...

Comment: Would you settle for Patagonia?

Comment: If you're going to walk so far, why in particular connect two major cities?

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth (probably not much), Google Maps gives a [walking route from Santiago to Buenos Aires](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Santiago,+Santiago+Metropolitan+Region,+Chile/Buenos+Aires,+Autonomous+City+of+Buenos+Aires,+Argentina/@-34.0240959,-65.0847121,7z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x9662c5410425af2f:0x8475d53c400f0931!2m2!1d-70.6692655!2d-33.4488897!1m5!1m1!1s0x95bcca3b4ef90cbd:0xa0b3812e88e88e87!2m2!1d-58.3815591!2d-34.6036844!3e2) as follows:

- Roughly south from Santiago to Chimbarongo, using smaller roads that roughly parallel Highway 5;
- Thence roughly southeast via Los Queñes and Canton to the border crossing at [Paso del Planchón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paso_del_Planch%C3%B3n);
- Thence roughly southeast to Bardas Blancas, and northeast to Malargüe;
- Thence almost straight east to Buenos Aires.

Total distance is 1,575 km, or about 319 hours of walking.

Also, the above link notes that the pass at Paso del Planchón is only open from November 1 to April 30, i.e., the summer.  Crossing the Andes by foot in the winter would, of course, be a Bad Idea, and even in the summer it'd be dicey.  [Some pictures of the route up to Paso del Planchón are available here;](http://www.dangerousroads.org/south-america/chile/4314-paso-del-planch%C3%B3n.html)  that page also notes that snow can come on suddenly, and that the nights are quite cold.